# SELECT UUID() inside an insert statment MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use `SELECT UUID()` INSIDE an insert query.
Here is my uery

```
INSERT INTO `posts`(`post_id`, `user_id`, `content`, `time`) VALUES (SELECT uuid(),1,'my content',mytime)
```

I'm getting error `a comma or a closing bracket was expected mysql near uuid`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`uuid` is a function, that you can use on its own without having to write select.

```
INSERT INTO `posts`(`post_id`, `user_id`, `content`, `time`) VALUES (uuid(),1,'my content',mytime)
```

Comment: Alternatively, I guess you could remove `VALUES (` and `)`